# I can not do yarn add because node-sass fails

Tags: yarnpkg

I have a problem with yarn add && yard build.

Especially node-sass

Whenever I'm trying to run node-sass it is giving me this error

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/user/all001/app/themes/alliance/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/bin/node" "/home/user/all001/app/themes/alliance/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/all001/app/themes/alliance/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

I really don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Node v14 is not stable version. It's recomennded that you need to use LTS version which is 12.18.4. Try to install this version and check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same error message when performing `npm install node-sass`. The only solution for me at the moment is to choose an older node version. Both v14 and v12 did not work, so I went back to v10. Luckily I had Node installed using nvm. You can run `nvm install v10.22.1`, for example. Use `nvm ls-remote` to see the available versions.

One difference, however, is that I tried to execute it on a Mac (`System Darwin 19.6.0`)